# VBA DateSerial function returning 12:00 AM even though the 3 inputs are correct

Tags: vba

Can someone please look at this piece of VBA code and tell me how its possible for VBA to return 12:00 am for DateSerial?

```
            If CurrentDay <= 15 And DaysToAdd <= 15 Then
                DueDate = DateSerial(Year(Today), Month(Today), DaysToAdd)
            ElseIf CurrentDay <= 15 And DaysToAdd > 15 Then                                           
                If (DaysToAdd / 15) > 1 Then
                    semimoleftover = DaysToAdd Mod 15
                Else
                    semimoleftover = 0
                End If
                DueDate = DateSerial(Year(Today), Month(Today), semimoleftover + 15)
            End If
```

Variable semimoleftover is an integer value, and Today is a date variable with today's date. I'm baffled why vba would return 12:00 am when the inputs seem to be correct. What's even more confounding is I had this exact code before and it was returning the date with no issues before. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you! EDIT: I solved this on my own. DateSerial was producing the correct value it's just that I had another line of code that was overriding my DueDate value later.

Comment: Is the value of semimoleeftover possibly greater than the number of days in a month? and is DueDate declared as a "Date" type?

Comment: No and yes. The value of semimoleftover if you look is DaysToAdd Mod 15 where DaysToAdd = 25 in the example I'm using, which makes semimoleftover = 10. DueDate is declared as Dim DueDate as Date at the top.

Comment: I can not replicate your problem, but this is what DateSerial is defined as - Returns a Date value representing a specified year, month, and day, with the time information set to midnight (00:00:00).

Comment: Thanks for your time mooseman...I actually figured it out on my own. Yes, it was returning correct value I was just overriding it with other lines from my code beneath it.